# Viewing console statements from command line in iOS React Native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, debugging, logging, console

When running an app in the Android Emulator, I can type `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` to view the console statements in a terminal, which is much faster than viewing them in Chrome or other debugger.

Is there a similar command in macOS to view the console statements of an app running in iOS simulator?

Comment: If you're building through XCode go to `View > Debug Area > Activate Console`. You should hopefully see console.logs appear there.

Answer (score 1):

You can just stop the debugger and look for logs in Xcode or you can call this in terminal:

```
react-native log-ios
```

[Source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging)